# What is the minimum level of technology needed to explore a large flood volcanism event?

Tags: science-based, technological-development, volcanoes, geophysics, exploration

The world in question has had this flood volcanism event going on for longer than humanity has been around. It is comparable in size to the one that created the Columbia River Basalt Group and is located in a remote area. The flows are only spaced 5-10 years apart so they are quite frequent eruptions compared to most flood volcanism events.

The goal is to have people able to actively examine a large lava flow close up as it actively occurs with the chance of survival and return high enough that it's not just sending people to their deaths most of the time. Preferably with long term health effects that only seriously kick in around after retirement.

Note that flood volcanism events are extremely different in scale to a regular eruption. The amount of magma moving is far higher than that of a typical volcanic eruption in terms of volume and covering a far wider area, however they aren't nearly as explosive.

Comment: A [tag:science-based] answer requires you to specifiy the exact (e.g. [tag:science-based]) goal of the investigation. As written your question is too vague to give you an objective best answer. The technology needed to investigate the gasses (per @David.R's good answer) is quite a bit different than the technology needed to investigate the chemical composition of lava that hasn't yet been tainted by the atomosphere.

Comment: @JBH probably s hould've added it but i re ally don't like editing my questions in ways that make existing answers not make sense

Comment: Fair enough. Please keep it in mind for the future. Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

Exploring hot basalt lava is fairly easy. Simply walk up to a point where you can watch it. See the recent tourism in Iceland to watch the lava flow or the tourist boats to watch Hawaii build new land.

The long term effects come not from viewing the lava flow, but from the gasses released during the eruption. Flood volcanism has been connected with global climate changes and mass extinctions. The suspected cause of the extinctions is due to gasses expelled during the eruptions. For example, the Laki eruption in 1783 in Iceland released so much fluorine that it killed a lot of people in Iceland and caused food problems in Britain. Flood basalt eruptions emit a lot of carbon dioxide and then a lot of sulfur dioxide. Both have major effects on climate. https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.2120441119

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need to walk there? These would be "cursed" lands, were people venture to do buisness and then quickly leave. Every quary into the pancake plateau reveals the geologic history. Of course, every time the orchard growing on it is replanted from little forests on hills surviving the catastrophe. And there are cursed villages that survive in deep lava tubes ending in said hills. It's insane what humanity can survive and even thrive in. Vine from Mount vesuvius is great and people come from afar to see pancake ruins and cylinder wall towns.

There is even religion and a fire-pancake festival. It's only ever a catastrophe if you can't plan for it. Roman level technology is enough to make a lava flooded plateau volcano habitable.